# Get servlet context in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my jsp I use `<%String base = (String)application.getAttribute("base");%>`

I tried to use 'base' in **javascript** but not work. Below is my javascript:

```
<script>
    var newBase = <%=base%>;
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: if I use 'newBase', I can get the 'base' value

Comment: Have you tried printing this `<%String base = (String)application.getAttribute("base");%>`Does base is not null?

Comment: I already tried and it not null. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rather try it out like this ,

set the value to the `hidden` field ,

`input type="hidden" id="hidVal" name="txt2" value="${base}"/>`

And in your java script ,

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById('hidVal').value;
alert(x);
</script>
```

**Update** :

```
var newBase = '<%=base%>';
```

You are missing the quotes to treat the value as string .

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Welcome :) Comment here if you face any issues with it

Comment: both method work but I prefer second method. Thanks san krish.:)

Comment: Happy to help :) . first one might be useful while validating forms

Answer (score 1):

This is the eplanation www.w3schools.com give for location object property pathname:
pathname:   Sets or returns the path name of a URL
In our case the javascript file wich is in your context.

The first element is that pathname is the context
So you split the attribute (see the split method in javascript String) and return it.
This should do.

```
<script language='javascript'>
    function servletContext() {
        var sc = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        return "/"+sc[1];
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!